# Commands to manage services and applications in a failover cluster

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, failovercluster

There is a [pretty decent suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461009.aspx) of Powershell commandlets for managing Microsoft Failover Clusters, including commands for starting and stopping nodes. However, I am interested in the equivalent commands for the following tasks involved in managing a failover cluster:

"Bring this service or application online"

"Take this service or application offline"

"Move this service or application to another node"

I have to assume these commands are available in a different commandlet suite (if they exist at all), but I cannot find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for are the commands for `Group`, such as `Start-ClusterGroup`, `Stop-ClusterGroup`, and `Move-ClusterGroup`.

Comment: Thanks! I guess this is because clustered services and applications are groups of resources. Still, that is NOT an intuitive mapping between the UI and the commands!